# Firebase Not Refreshing Image (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, image

I am using firebase with react to store images so that the user can upload them there and then have them be displayed and I manage to display the uploaded image but when I refresh the page. The image gets removed, my function userProfileImage() does not seem to update the image, how can I keep the image?

```
      const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
      const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
      const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    
      const handleChange = e => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
          setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        }
      };

    const imagesListRef = ref(storage, "images/");


    useEffect(() => {
    list(imagesListRef).then((response) => {
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          setUrl(url);
          console.log(url);
        });
      });
    });
  }, []);
        
     

      const handleUpload = () => {
        const uploadTask = 
        storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
        uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          snapshot => {
            const progress = Math.round(
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            );
            setProgress(progress);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          },
          () => {
            storage
              .ref("images")
              .child(image.name)
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(url => {
                setUrl(url);
              });
          }
        );
        userProfileImage();
      };
   
      return (
        <div className='App'>
        <Header/>
        <br />
        <br />
        {progress > 0 && progress < 100 ?
        <progress value={progress} max="100" /> : <div></div>
        }
        <div class="proPic">
        <Avatar src={url} sx={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} />
        <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleUpload}>Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: you are only showing the image after the user uploads an image, there should be a function that get the user's avatar from firebase

Answer (score 0):

When you are refreshing, all the components will also be refreshed. As a result all the states will be reinitialized. So when you refresh, url will be null again. So you should retrieve the image when the component is refreshed. You can retrive the uploaded image inside a useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(()=>{
//retrieve image
},[]}
```

Comment: I am confused how to write the useEffect hook with my handleUpload function inside it.

Comment: you will need to add a new relation {userId,imageUrl} to your firebase db. Then when handleUpload function returns the url(where setUrl has been called), you will have to save the record to the database. Then inside the useEffect hook you will have to retrive the record from the database.

Comment: I am attempting to do a useEffect but it would be easier if there was a way for me to get the reference of the last image that was uploaded so I can retrieve the url and set it.

Comment: you can use browser's localStorage to save the url. But if you change the browser or device, the saved data will be lost. So the best way is to retrieve the record from the db.

Comment: Do you have an example in code where it saves your uploaded image when you refresh with useEffect?